# How do I obtain the type of a Java instance in Jython?

Tags: java, python, jython

```
from java.util import LinkedList
type(LinkedList())
```

The code above only gives "type 'javainstance" as output, however I wish to know the real Java instance type, which should be "LinkedList" in that case. Is this possible?

Thank you!

by the way, my version is jython 2.2.1

Comment: sorry, I want Jython to tell me LinkedList, but it only tells me "javainstance"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Howard, if you are on older Jython then try to call

`LinkedList.getClass()`

and

`object.getClass().getName()`

Comment: And in true jython style, that can be abbreviated as `object.class.name`. Parentheses Purged.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to use

```
lst =LinkedList()
lst.class
```

Similar to the way that you would in java.

Answer (score -1):

Just installed the latest jython last night.  Let's take a look...

```
Jython 2.5.3rc1 (2.5:8fd14231e553, Aug 7 2012, 10:29:09)
[Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (Sun Microsystems Inc.)] on java1.6.0_31
>>> type(LinkedList)
<type 'java.lang.Class'>
>>> l = LinkedList()
>>> type( l )
<type 'java.util.LinkedList'>
```

What version of Jython do you have?  I know from experience that some levels of inspection only appeared in later versions.

Comment: thank you. you're lucky to work with the latest Jython, I'm actually working with Jython 2.2

Comment: I worked with that.  And the older versions don't let you look that deep under the hood.

Comment: try then this code below I posted. that is from older Jython. I cannot tell you unfortunately if the versions match.